# FileNotFoundError when creating new file

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, filenotfounderror

I'm building a scraper that would automatically download files and course material from my college moodle page, but I'm receiving a couple of extremely weird errors. One that I think I can't solve is this FileNotFoundError:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moodleScraper.py", line 88, in <module>
    open(name[:size-5]+".pdf", 'wb').write(response.content)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'course calendar.pdf'
```

To contextualize this, I've written a code that's supposed to open new files and download in them the course content. It does that flawlessy for some pdfs, but for others it gives the above error, which makes no sense to me.

I've tried to use only the option 'w' instead of 'wb', but it would only increase the problems. Other ways of trying to download files haven't worked (tryed finding the download button by id="download" with selenium for instance, but hasn't worked).

Here's the chunk of code that I used for this (it uses requests, selenium and beautiful soup):

```py
s = requests.Session()
selenium_user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
s.headers.update({"user-agent": selenium_user_agent})

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
linkers = []  
resources = []  
folders = []
contents = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    linkers.append([a['href'],a.get_text()])

# gets all items
for item in linkers:
    for word in item:
        if "resource" in word:
            resources.append(item)
        if "folder" in word:
            folders.append(word)
        if "content" in word:
            contents.append(item)

# download pdf resources and contents
for address, name in resources:
    response = s.get(address)
    size = len(name)
    open(name[:size-5]+".pdf", 'wb').write(response.content)
for address, name in contents:
    response = s.get(address)
    open(name, 'wb').write(response.content)
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because your loop calls `open()` over and over without ever closing the files, and eventually you run out of file handles?  Try closing the file in the loop.

Comment: Or maybe it's because some of the filenames are identical, so it tries to re-open a file that is already open and was never closed?

Comment: @JohnGordon When testing this out with a simple python script, I can't replicate this behaviour. Python reopens the file and overwrites its content without any problem. It can of course also be possible that this is differen on T3X3K's operating system.

Comment: @The_spider It's very odd that opening a file _for writing_ would throw a FileNotFoundError.  I was just trying to think of any weird edge case that could cause it.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the filename itself?  Is that a plain ASCII space in the filename, or is it some odd unicode character that just _looks_ like a space?

Comment: Is there any way you can reproduce this *without* the selenium dependency? Might cut down on the guesswork required.

Comment: @JohnGordon first of all, thanks for answering:) Anyways, you were kinda right: some of the names in resources and contents contain either parenthesis or / (like if there is a date in the name of the file). These are the characters that make the program crash when calling fopen, so now I have to figure out what do to solve this problem.

Comment: If the name contains a slash, then the part before the slash would be interpreted as a subdirectory name, and if that subdirectory does not exist, then yes you would get the error.  But the specific filename you posted was `course calendar.pdf` which does not contain a slash...

Comment: @JohnGordon when I copied that error I was just trying some random stuff on the terminal, and I don't remember what happened there exactly. But I observed that in general, if I ran the whole script the problems were given by the above characters. I added a `linkers.append([a['href'],a.get_text().replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(' ','_').replace('/','.')])` and now it works perfectly fine. I don't know why, maybe it has to do with the other dependencies? Do you by chance have a sense what other characters might give problems in the future?